# File input/output in C unformatted

Tags: c, string, file, struct, io

```
typedef char string20[21];

struct x{
string20 a;
string20 b;
string20 c;
};
```

How do I scan a text file and store their values on my structure? I can't think of an easy way on how to do this and btw I'm just learning I/O can't find any good tutorial on internet please help
the file format is:

```
3
FCODE=random
FKEY=shit
FSRC=hi
```

how do i store "random" in a and etc... I know I should use strcpy ofcourse

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832514/from-file-to-structure-in-c?lq=1

Comment: Yes, `strcpy()` is a safe bet. But **make sure to not overwrite your arrays.** Hint: post your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fgets` function to a single line.

```
 eg: fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_SIZE, my_io);
```

Use `strchr` or `strtok` to find exact data.

```
 eg: ptr = strchr(buf, '=');
```

copy into your structure

```
 eg: strcpy(my_structy.ele, ptr);
```

PS: don't forget validations. refer man pages