# Copying unformatted file into structure

Tags: c, string, struct, io

```
#define MAX 20
typedef char string20[21];

struct flight_list{
    char fcode[21];
    string20 srccity;
    string20 descity;
    int deptime[2];/** deptime[0] hours, deptime[1] minutes **/
    int duration;
    int eta[2];/**eta[0] hours , eta[1] minutes**/
    int nctr;

};
void load_flight(struct flight_list flight[]){
    int num,i;
    char* ptr;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("flightFILES.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);
    while(!feof(fp)){
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){
            fgets(flight[i].fcode,100,fp);
            fgets(flight[i].srccity,100,fp);
            fgets(flight[i].descity,100,fp);
            fscanf(fp,"%d %d",flight[i].deptime[0],flight[i].deptime[1]);
            fscanf(fp,"%d",flight[i].duration);
            fscanf(fp,"%d %d",flight[i].eta[0],flight[i].eta[1]);

            ptr=strchr(flight[i].fcode,'=');
            strcpy(flight[i].fcode,ptr+1);

            ptr=strchr(flight[i].srccity,'=');
            strcpy(flight[i].srccity,ptr+1);

            ptr=strchr(flight[i].descity,'=');
            strcpy(flight[i].descity,ptr+1);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);



}
```

every time I run this function It crashes I just followed what he advice me to do please help me I'm suppose to copy the contents inside of this file to my array of structures
the file format is this:

```
4
FCODE=CHIX
SRCCITY=MAN
DESTCITY=KAN
DEPARTURE=12 10
DURATION=30
FCODE=PAUL
SRCCITY=KAN
DESTCITY=CHG
DEPARTURE=13 10
DURATIOn=60
```

[File input/output in C unformatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879109/file-input-output-in-c-unformatted/22879147#22879147)

Comment: ,`fscanf(fp,"%d %d",flight[i].deptime[0],flight[i].deptime[1]);` not match. and need address of Variable. and nothing eta time in file.

Comment: done that but still crashes :(

Comment: `while(!feof(fp)){` bad. and `fgets(flight[i].fcode,100,fp);` : 100 -> 21.

Comment: can you please elaborate what are you saying? thanks :) @BLUEPIXY

Comment: You would enter the following loop EOF will not be set when you have finished reading the last record. To cause a segmentation violation if you try to process the data in the extra loop such.

Comment: and Buffer size for fgets you specified is 100 but the actual size is 21.